QT designer Layout margins are not editable
I have UI file generated in QT designer 6.5.1 using python 3.9. This was pushed into git. Now I have downloaded in new machine where I have installed python 3.12.3 with QT designer 6.7.1. Like to fix if there is any gap on newer version and make code cleaner.
Now I found that I could not edit any frame layout margins sizes. I tried changing layout style,etc., nothing worked. I have structure like below.
"MainWindow"
  |->QWidget (Layout margins are not editable)
       |-> QScrolArea
                 |->QWidget (Layout margins are not editable)
                      |-...and so on

The screenshot

Please show some light on this to fix this issue.
List of items tried :

I tried updating frame style.
I tried creating new frame under my existing widget. Applied horizontal layout in new frames and tried editing layout left/right/top/bottom margins in property editor. I could not edit it.


That graphical glitch means that it's 99.9% unrelated to Python. A month ago a similar PYSIDE-2733 issue was filed, again with an unrelated PySide tag. Not sure it's the same, though. I suggest you to file a report on https://bugreports.qt.io with proper version info (note: you should report proper OS, Qt and Designer version info: in theory, Designer follows the same Qt version, but I wouldn't be sure about it).

Thanks @musicamante Just created ticket -PYSIDE-2778 [https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-2778] . The issue reported at 2733 also similar to my issue though i could not confirm.

After raising issue in QT i got reply as my issue is duplicate of QTBUG-125983 . Seems they already fixed and merged in qt/qttools. But i dont understand how can i use this version of pyside6.

Right now it seems that the only options you have is to downgrade to 6.7.0 or clone the 6.7.2 from the official Qt repository and build it on your own, until it's officially released.

Agree. Let me downgrade version and will try it out.

Finally it worked by downgrading the package by running pip install --force-reinstall PySide6==6.7.0 Thanks @musicamante for your guidance and help

Why not answer your own question?

Finally it worked by downgrading the package by running
pip install --force-reinstall PySide6==6.7.0

